# ShellSort of Array of tweet objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm

trying to sort tweet objects according to the number of user's followers. The data and object keys are custom from a mysql database containing data that I've been collecting for an app im building. I have an array called dstore, of Individual objects that look as follows :

#### #

```
{tweet_text: "so I'm a bit surprised that people are... surprised. that the "action plan" to cool Toronto housing is just...meetings."
user_FollowersCount: "1415"
user_ProfileImageUrl: "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/821936571842707456/gPPRWsyS_normal.jpg"
user_ScreenName: "RosalindR"}

public shellsrt(dstore){

   var gaps = [20,10,1];

   for (var g = 0; g <  gaps.length; ++g) {

      for(var i = gaps[g]; i < dstore.length; ++i)
      {
            var temp = dstore[i];
            var followcount = parseInt(temp['user_FollowersCount']);
            var j = i;

            if(dstore[j - gaps[g]] !== undefined){

              var gapdiff = parseInt(dstore[j - gaps[g]]['user_FollowersCount']);

               while( j >= gaps[g] && gapdiff > followcount ) 
                {   

                   if ( dstore[gapdiff] != undefined) {
                         dstore[j] = dstore[gapdiff];            
                       }       

                     j -= gaps[g];
                }
        }
           dstore[j] = temp;                     
      }
 }
  console.log(dstore);
   //return dstore;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you've written your own sorting function instead of using the built-in `Array#sort` method?

Comment: @barmar - im trying to implement a shellsort function. Currently working through "Datastructures and Algorithms in Javascript" book [O'Reilly Publishing]

Comment: Okay, so you've told us what you're trying to do, and you've showed us some code. Does it work? If not, then what's the specific problem? Have you tried single-stepping your code while sorting a small array to see where the problem might be? You have a debugger: use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like this

```js
let arr = [{tweet_text: "so I'm that the ",action_plan :" to cool Toronto housing is just...meetings.",user_FollowersCount:"1415",user_ProfileImageUrl: "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/821936571842707456/gPPRWsyS_normal.jpg",user_ScreenName: "RosalindR"},
{tweet_text: "so I'm that the ",action_plan :" to cool Toronto housing isjust...meetings.",user_FollowersCount: "1485",user_ProfileImageUrl: "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/821936571842707456/gPPRWsyS_normal.jpg",user_ScreenName: "RosalindR"},
{tweet_text: "so I'm that the ",action_plan :" to cool Toronto housing isjust...meetings.",user_FollowersCount:"115",user_ProfileImageUrl: "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/821936571842707456/gPPRWsyS_normal.jpg",user_ScreenName: "RosalindR"}]

let op = arr.sort((a,b)=> a.user_FollowersCount - b.user_FollowersCount)

console.log(op)
```